# How to sort DataColumns by First In First Out

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, datatable, datacolumn

I'm not sure if the question is correct but that's what I'm trying to do.

I have an Import/Export tool that import/export test cases in TestRail using a Matrix spreadsheet template that looks like this (AP=Applicable, NA=Not Applicable):

```
Sections        Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test4 | Test5
Section 1         NA  |  AP   |  AP   |  AP   |  NA
Section 2         AP  |  NA   |  AP   |  AP   |  AP
Section 3         AP  |  AP   |  AP   |  NA   |  AP
```

So once in TestRail it looks like this:

- Section 1

  - Test2
  - Test3
  - Test4
- Section 2

  - Test1
  - Test3
  - Test4
  - Test5
- Section 3

  - Test1
  - Test2
  - Test3
  - Test5

But when I export from TestRail, the columns are not in the same order as the Import:

```
Sections        Test2 | Test3 | Test4 | Test1 | Test5
Section 1         AP  |  AP   |  AP   |       |  
Section 2             |  AP   |  AP   |  AP   |  AP
Section 3         AP  |  AP   |       |  AP   |  AP
```

This is the code I have so far using DataTable and by trying to detect the previous Test Case... but after some test, it is not accurate/working as intended at all... especially with a big amount of Sections and Tests:

```
String previousTC = String.Empty;

// For each Test Case
// Adds column to the Matrix table for each new Test Cases
foreach (var tcase in currentCases)
{
    if (!dtMatrix.Columns.Contains(tcase.title))
    {
        // Adds a new Column if TestCases does not exist
        dtMatrix.Columns.Add(tcase.title, typeof(string));
    }
    else
    {
        if (dtMatrix.Columns.Contains(previousTC))
        {
            // Gets the position of the previous TestCase 
            // in order to put the new one right after
            var previous = dtMatrix.Columns.IndexOf(previousTC);
            var current = dtMatrix.Columns.IndexOf(tcase.title);
            if (previous >= current)
            {
                dtMatrix.Columns[current].SetOrdinal(previous);
            }
        }
    }
    previousTC = tcase.title;
}
```

PLEASE NOTE that Test1 to 5 are only to explain my issue and can be anything and not in alphabetical order.

So I would need some help to find the right algorithm that will fix my sort order issue.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
I thought that maybe, based on TestRail's suites, I could find a way to merge them.. then keeping track of each merged Test Cases columns.

Comment: So if the columns aren't supposed to appear in alphabetical order, and they're not supposed to appear in the same order as the `currentCases`, what order *are* they supposed to appear in?

Comment: By ID... each test cases has their own ID, which are in order per sections.  I need to find a way to track in which order they have been imported.